# Auth Bearer Token in Redux Saga

Tags: reactjs, http, redux, axios, redux-saga

i'm trying to authenticate in my API with a Bearer token, that is returning from this saga, and i want to pass it for the Authorization HTTP Header, does anyone know how to do it? Thank you.

```
import { takeLatest, call, put, all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { apiCore } from '@/services/api';
import { ActionType } from 'typesafe-actions';
import * as actions from './actions';

export function* signIn(action: ActionType<typeof actions.signInRequest>) {
  try {
    const { email, password } = action.payload;
    const { data } = yield call(apiCore.post, '/auth/myapp/login', {
      email,
      password
    });

    yield put(actions.signInSuccess({ token: data.result.token }));

    **yield call(apiCore.get, '', PASS THE TOKEN SOMEHOW? (data.result.token))????**

  } catch (err) {
    yield put(actions.signInFailure());
  }
}

export default all([takeLatest('@login/SIGN_IN_REQUEST', signIn)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the argument as the 2nd parameter to the `call()` function.

As explained in the docs:

> **call(fn, ...args)**
>
> Creates an Effect description that instructs the middleware to call the function >fn with args as arguments.
>
> fn: Function - A Generator function, or normal function which either returns a >Promise as result, or any other value.
>
> args: Array - An array of values to be passed as arguments to fn